# When is move assignment called for std::deque emplace()?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, deque

As per the description of `emplace()` method in both std::vector and std::deque -

> if the required location has been occupied by an existing element, the inserted element is constructed at another location at first, and then move assigned into the required location.

```
NOTE: This is true, only when std::vector reallocation doesn't happen on emplace.
```

When I **move construct** by **emplacing** one more element to the vector emplace() example, I see the description of emplace() stands true (when reallocation doesn't happen on emplace). i.e. The last element in the container is move constructed, rest all are move assigned.

```
NOTE: create a new object A four{"four"}, then move construct by emplace
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace

Understandbly the o/p is different for `std::deque` in this link
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/emplace

What conditions would generate the **move assignment** o/p in `std::deque`, as it does in `std::vector` on emplace()?

Comment: This is a short example link that can be used 
https://godbolt.org/z/4Mdvv4b5o

I'm inserting all elements at container.begin()

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, I don't think that the behaviour here is is guaranteed by the standard. It's just a practical behaviour that arises from the implementation.

You may be able to reproduce the assignment by emplacing to the middle of the deque i.e. somewhere that isn't either of the ends of the deque. In your short example, you are emplacing to the front end, in which case it happens to be possible to construct the element in-place, without needing an extra assignment.

Comment: Thanks. I can see the move assignment with your suggestion.
I see, so this is possibly implementation dependant, which could be adapted by common compilers. Any place you could direct me to lookup for standards?

Comment: @ppadhy See the section [containers], and in particular [sequence.reqmts] and [vector] and [deque]. You may notice the lack of rules with condition "if the required location has been occupied by an existing element".

Comment: The standard doesn't say that directly, but http://wg21.link/lwg2164 explains why these temporary objects are required

Comment: @Cubbi I understood the requiements of temporary objects. I have two follow up questions:  </br>
**1.** Is it guaranteed that move-assignment always happens on vector::emplace() when the required location is occupied? 
>>>I found this to be true only when capacity is not exhausted (Tested in GCC and Clang latest versions)


**2.** When is the move-assignment happening on deque::emplace(), if the specified location is occupied by something else?

FYI, just curious to understand how the statement from cppreference works for deque::emplace